# Why isn't my textview updating?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview

so I have a textview which I'm trying to update from an asynctask. The message I want to update it to correctly prints to the console but for some reason it doesn't update the textview. Here are the relevant bits of code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private MqttClient client;
    private String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
    private TextView tv;
    ...
```

I declare the textview here, then I assign it in the onCreate() method:

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
```

Then in my asynctask I have this snippet which runs everytime a new message is posted to MQTT:

```
@Override
        public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message)
                throws Exception {
            System.out.println(message);
            if(message.toString().toLowerCase().contains(str)){
                Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)");
                Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(message.toString());
                while(matcher.find()){
                    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
                    tv.setText("testing");
                }
            }
        }
```

The message correctly prints how I want it to the console but it doesn't update the textview and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are calling your callback `messageArrived` on the UI Thread.

From a background thread, you can write to the log, but you can not update UI elements (like a textbox).

You can run code from a background task on the UI thread using runOnUIThread

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
    {       
        public void run() 
        {
            // update UI code
        }
    });
```

In you case, that would mean moving either the call to the callback (e.g. `callback.messageArrived(..)`) or setting the textview (`tv.setText("testing");`) from the runnable

Comment: That's perfect thanks so much I used the runOnUiThread code and that works now. I'm relatively new to Android Programming so learning about the threads and stuff is very interesting.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You should be updating your `TextView` in `onPostExecute()` of your `AsyncTask`.

Here is an example

```
protected void onPostExecute(Prams) {

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    tv.setText("testing");
}
```

Here the key point is you pass the result of your `protected doInBackground(Params)` to `onPostExecute()` and it will update your views on `UiThread`.

Hope it helps